# Django Registering two different types of users with different fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I want to create two users: `patient` and `doctor`. Both users will share some of the standard fields like `first_name`, `last_name`, etc. However, they should have different fields. Only the `doctor`, for example, will have fields like `expertise` and `days_available`.

I reviewed a similar question but it doesn't quite address what I need specifically. I don't necessarily need custom permissions/authentication as I simply need separate fields for each user. I've tried the last approach, extending the user model, but when I create the the user, it's not linked to the patient/doctor. I have to manually create a doctor and the link it to the user. 
How can the doctor/patient be automatically created when a user is created?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.is_patient = True
    pid = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True) #patient identification

class Doctor(models.Model):
    upin = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #unique physician identification number
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.is_doctor = True
    expertise = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    days_available = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

Comment: How are you creating your users? The normal way calls `create_user()` method on the `UserManager`. Override this method.

Comment: I'm using a `UserCreationForm` like so:

`class DoctorCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','email','phone','upin','expertise','appointments_per_day',)`

Comment: If you don't want to link it via form / view, I'd recommend you're having a look at [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/). You can automatically create the appropriate Doctor/Patient models when a user is created.

Comment: I am linking it via form/view. I can register a user through a `signup.html` that I created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)--specifically the second option: "Extending the User Model using a One-to-One link." The author recommends using signals to perform actions automatically when a User object is created/updated. Maybe try something like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.is_patient = True
    pid = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True) #patient identification

class Doctor(models.Model):
    upin = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) #unique physician identification number
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.is_doctor = True
    expertise = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    days_available = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.is_patient:
            Patient.objects.create(user=instance)
        elif instance.is_doctor:
            Doctor.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_patient:
        instance.patient.save()
    elif instance.is_doctor:
        instance.doctor.save()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your `User` model has by default `objects` set to `auth.models.UserManager`. You should override that method:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ... # fields
    objects = MedicalUserManager()

class MedicalUserManager(models.UserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
        # pop all fields you want to use for `Doctor` or `Patient` from `extra_fields`
        doctor_pin = extra_fields.pop('doctor_pin', None)
        pid = extra_fields.pop('pid', None)
        user = super().create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
        if doctor_pin:
            doctor = Doctor.objects.create(user=user, upin=doctor_pin)
            user.is_doctor = True  # not needed if `is_doctor` is in `extra_fields` because it would have been saved when creating the `User`
            user.save()
        elif pid:
            patient = Patient.objects.create(user=user, pid=pid)
            user.is_patient = True
            user.save()
        return user
```